# How to get Tracelistnername from app.config

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
<listeners>
          <add name="mylistener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\application.txt" />
    <add name="mylistener2" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\application2.txt" />
    <remove name="mylistener"/>
    <remove name="mylistener2"/>
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

I have the above app.config file.I want to get name from `<remove>` tag.Can somebody help me to get the remove tag name from codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the name of the current listeners using the following snippet:

```
foreach (TraceListener listener in System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners)
{
    Console.WriteLine(listener.Name);
}
```

But there is no way to get the names of listeners removed immediately. Your app.config registers two listeners and immediately removes it, what doesn't make sense (to me).